# How to disable VMFusion mouse capture?

Tags: vmware-fusion

Is it possible to disable mouse capture for some VMs?
For example, I have a Ubuntu server installed and everytime I had to <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> to get the mouse back even though I only use the keyboard in the VM.

Comment: Not on Ubuntu server. It has to be an OS that supports "pointer intergration".